# Handling multiple node by Chef

Tags: chef-infra

Example, I have 1 recipe file, 5 target nodes. How do I apply the recipe file to all the target node?
Any commands I need to use or ? I'm not aiming to go into each and every target node to run the chef-client, my aim is to maybe by just single command or using other methods to get this done.

If you know how, do comment and give some reference answer as well.

Thank you.

Comment: What you ask for is ability to _push_ changes to nodes. Chef in fact advocates _pulling_ changes. When you have a chef-client service running periodically on node, pulling new recipes and updating the node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run chef-client on multiple nodes via knife ssh command like:

```
knife ssh "role:app" "sudo chef-client" -x myuser -p 22
```

More info about knife ssh you can [find here](https://docs.getchef.com/knife_ssh.html).

More info about search syntax you can [find here](https://docs.getchef.com/knife_search.html).

Another approach is to have cron job that would run `chef-client` every N minutes, and then your nodes will be updated when you upload changes to chef server.

Comment: But if the node has different user name and password? How should I go about?

Comment: By my opinion if nodes have a same roles they should be basically the same, so as users on them. For authentication you should use ssh keys not passwords. If you worry about security, ssh access should be only available from private network (VPN) if it's available by your hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

You upload the cookbook once to the Chef server, the nodes then pick it up from there.

[Here on learnchef.com](http://learn.getchef.com/ubuntu/get-ready-to-add-another-server/) is the corresponding explanation.