# Run chef recipe multiple nodes at same time

Tags: chef-infra

I have 100 nodes connect with chef server. I have 1 recipe file, How do I apply the recipe file to 5 target node? How to run in single command.

Comment: There are a thousand ways.

Comment: knife ssh "platform:ubuntu*" "service nginx restart" -x yourusername -a ipaddress

Comment: What's a group in the Chef context? Please edit your question and update it with more details. It's pretty unclear, what your environment is.

Comment: Btw. you might overload your Chef server a bit, if 100 nodes simultaneously hit it.

Comment: I need to apply the path file in dev environment only.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26964594/handling-multiple-node-by-chef

Answer (score -1):

You can find the introductory Chef tutorials at https://learn.chef.io/

That's a good starting point for how to use Chef. You probably want to use `knife node edit` to update the run lists on those 5 nodes.